# Increase Message Size Service Fabric

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

I have hosted a Web API in Service Fabric and Posting data on it. Currently My object size is around 10 MB but default limit is 4 MB. I know its not a good practice to post such large objects but as per my need I have to do so.

Please help to increase the default message size limit.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124021/send-large-stream-to-servicefabric-service

Comment: Thanks Bruce!! It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating Service Listener, add this as a parameter to increase message size to be accepted by microservice in service-fabric.

```
    return new[]
    {
      new ServiceReplicaListener(con=> new 
      FabricTransporServiceRemotingListener(con,this,remotingListenerSettings: new 
      FabricTransportremotingListenerSettings(){
      MaxMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
      },serializationProvider: new ServiceRemotingSerializationProvider())),
    };
```

This honors the message size to be increased which bypasses the default message size.